# Where can I find the indexes for Search API on the Google Developer Console?

Tags: google-app-engine

I can't find the indexes I have created with Search API on the Google Developer Console. Anybody know where I can view them in the console?

Answer (score 3):

They are not visible on the Developer Console for some reason. Go to https://appengine.google.com and then select the Text Search in the left panel to see the Indexes and documents for the Search aPI